# adding csrf tag before include tag breaks the form

Tags: django, django-forms

The include tag doesn't work with csrf tag. The form works fine if it is removed. form1 and form2 only have fields.

```
<form novalidate action="{% url 'action' %}" method="post" class="form xl:ml-10 owl-carousel"
      id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'form1.html' %}
    {% include 'form2.html' %}
    {% include 'submit.html' %}
</form>
```

UPDATED

form1.html

```
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
```

form2.html

```
<label for="age">Age:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br>
```

Comment: have you used csrf_token in `form1.html` `form2.html` ?

Comment: No I have not included the tag form1.html and form2.html

Comment: try there also.

Comment: Can you show what's inside your included files and how your view `action` is defined ?

Comment: @sunilghimire that works, my concern is that all the forms ultimately build up one form. Which is submitted in the end. This is a multistage form. So it doesn't feel right to add the tag to every stage.